# scraping with xpath, giving an error

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying to get the text from a page scrape using xpath, now I keep getting an error returned and no idea why! - bare in mind I am a very new php user, this is for a university project that I've taken on and its prooving to be very challenging :P but hey it should be.

Heres the code,

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.amazon.co.uk/New-Apple-iPod-touch-Generation/dp/B0040GIZTI/ref=br_lf_m_1000333483_1_1_img?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&pf_rd_p=229345967&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_t=1401&pf_rd_i=1000333483&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1ZW9HJW2KN2C2MTRJH60');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$in_stock = $xpath->query("/html/body/div[@id='divsinglecolumnminwidth']/form[@id='handleBuy']/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/span");



?>
```

I get the following error...

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
>   [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end
>   tag : head in Entity, line: 2664 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\domxpath.php
>   on line 19

About a hundred times!

Any help really appreciated! , it must be really easy to fix :P

Comment: It looks like a parser error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$expr = "/html/body/div[@id='divsinglecolumnminwidth']/form[@id='handleBuy']/table[3]/tr[3]/td/div/span";
$nodes = $xpath->query($expr); // returns DOMNodeList object
// you can check length property i.e. $nodes->length
echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue; // get first DOMNode object and its value
```

Also you need to add stametent for [suppressing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449907/scraping-with-xpath-giving-an-error/5450021#5450021). I think that for performance reasons it's better to use absolute XPath expression, but relative //form[@id='handleBuy']/table[3]/tr[3]/td/div/span works as well and is more elastic.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this line first in your code to stop displaying errors, this is particularly helpful when your document is an HTML page and if you don't know if it is a well formed XML doc .

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php

Comment: Thanks, although I now get the following error, which now seems to be referring to the echo statement. 

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\domxpath.php on line 27

Comment: You probably tried to echo your `$in_stock` variable, but you can't. This variable is a `DOMNodeList` element (http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) so you can only see it's size with `length` attribute or iterate through it to have `DOMNode` .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
//form[@id='handleBuy']/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/span
```